# LUA replace instances of string

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have a string `x = "a b c d e f g e b"`
And I am trying to replace every instance of `x b` where x is any character with the letter `z` let's say, so the above should be `x = z c d e f g z`. I have looked up in examples but they all mention specific characters replacement with `string.gsub`, how can the above be done?

Comment: Do you mean to replace any *letter* followed with 1 space and exactly 1 letter? What if you have `a bc c b`, what is the expected result
?

Comment: `any letter, space, b` should result in a `z` so that should give `zc z`

Comment: Ok, so it is much easier, you do not even need to check if a  whole word is matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
string.gsub(x, "%a b", "z")
```

where `%a` matches any letter.

See more on [Lua pattern here](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html).

[Lua demo](https://ideone.com/45A18f):

```
x = [[a b c d e f g e b]]
res, _ = string.gsub(x, "%a b", "z")
print(res)
-- z c d e f g z
```